# Passing array to another VC (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have **ViewControler.swift** (main) and **ViewControllerHistory.swift** (for history).

How can I make the history stored in VC (for history) **after pressing the button (=).**

I have code to store the values into an array.

How can I send this array to the **ViewControllerHistory.swift** (for history)

```
@IBAction func EqualSave(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let result = "\(firstOperand)\(equalitySignPressed)\(secondOperand)="
    ArrayWithResults.append(result as AnyObject)
}
```

[**VC (for history)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivaQK.png)

**[Screen Main VC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHwkY.jpg)**

Comment: There are a couple of ways of doing this depending on if you are using Storyboards segues or programmatically moving to your ViewControllerHistory.swift.  Need more into to help.

Comment: @Chi-HwaMichaelTing I using Storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using storyboards, typically you'll use a segue to link from one view controller to another. In that case, prepareForSegue is the usual place to pass info from one view controller to another.

You need to create a property in the destination view controller to receive the array.

If you add a property `array` of custom type `YourArrayType`, to `ViewControllerHistory`, the first part of that class might look like this:

```
class ViewControllerHistory: UIViewController {
   var array: YourArrayType 
}
```

And then the code in the first view controller might look like this:

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   guard let destination = segue.destination as? ViewControllerHistory else 
   { 
      return 
   }
   destination.array = arrayWithResults
}
```

A couple of notes:

Don't use arrays of AnyObject type. Swift supports arrays containing specific types of objects. You should prefer arrays of a specific type over arrays of `AnyObject`

Variable names should start with a lower case letter. Class names and types should start with an upper-case letter. Therefore your `ArrayWithResults` should be `arrayWithResults` instead.

If you're invoking your `ArrayWithResults` view controller directly rather than with a segue, you can simply create the view controller using `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`, set the property, then present or push it.

Comment: var array = ArrayWithResults (Error - Use of unresolved identifier 'ArrayWithResults')

Comment: My answer is not intended to be copy/pasted into your code. You'll have to edit it to fit into your program.